# Number Groupings for Coding

Tags: real-numbers

On a coding assignment, I want my program to detect 3 groups of any number going from 1 to 6.
eg.
1
3
4
5
5
3
5
There is 1 group of three 5's but how would I specify that there are three fives? Also, how may pairs of 3 are there in the numbers going from one to 6?
eg. 1,2,3 or 4,5,6.

Answer (score 0):

You should post this on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/), and not Mathematics... But anyway, you can create a 2nd array of size 6 (since we have 6 optional values) and then loop through the original array, and for each value in it, add one in the counter array (e.g. `counterArr[value-1]++`). Then all you need to do is just loop through `counterArr` and check for values >= 3.

Comment: Thanks so much!